# Which is the correct verb?

Tags: vocabulaire, verbes

Please can someone answer which sentence is correct?

*Il a commencé à jouer du piano il y a un an.*

OR

*Il a commencé à joué du piano il y a un an.*

Comment: One should not confuse the **a** of the verb avoir : *il **a** joué* (hence past participle **joué**) with the preposition **à** : *il a commencé **à** jouer* (hence infinitive **jouer**).

Comment: Tips : you have 3 verbs : *"a (avoir), commencé, jouer*" in different tenses [it is the first rule]  and ***a*** twice, one have to have an accent [this is the second rule in your example]. So  — 1° : ***a** + past participle*. 2° — ***à** + infinitive*. In this case the verb *commencer à* is used.

Answer (score 2):

*il a commencé à jouer* is the right one, I guess you could have asked any translator for that, deepl is a good one imo.

The rule is: after a preposition (in this case *à*) verbs are always at the infinitive form